# hive Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, cloudera

I am using pig 0.15, stored the file as ORC format like below.

```
loading_data= Load '/user/location/emp.csv' using PigStorage('\u241C') AS (
empno:long
,ename:chararray
,job:chararray
,mgr:float
,hiredate:chararray
,sal:bigdecimal
,comm:bigdecimal
,deptno:int
,flag:chararray
);

processed_data = FOREACH loading_data GENERATE
empno
,ename
,job
,mgr
,ToDate(hiredate,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm') as (hiredate:datetime)
,sal
,comm
,deptno
,flag;



store processed_data into '/user/myfolder/newLocation' using OrcStorage();
```

Now I am creating HIVE table like below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL Table emp123(
  empno    BIGINT,
  ename    STRING,
  job      String,
  mgr      FLOAT,
  hiredate DATE,
  sal      DECIMAL(15,2),
  comm     DECIMAL(10,2),
  deptno   int,
  flag     String
)
comment 'EMP test table'
stored as ORC
location '/user/myfolder/newLocation/'
```

Now I want to runt he below query will get an error.
hive> select * from emp123;
OK

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp
>   cannot be cast to java.sql.Date Time taken: 1.478 seconds

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Use timestamp instead of date for the HIVE table definition.Your PigScript has time part for the hireddate column.Hive Date types do not have a time of day component.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL Table emp123(
              empno    BIGINT,
              ename    STRING,
              job      String,
              mgr      FLOAT,
              hiredate timestamp,
              sal      DECIMAL(15,2),
              comm     DECIMAL(10,2),
              deptno   int,
              flag     String
)
comment 'EMP test table'
stored as ORC
location '/user/myfolder/newLocation/'
```